# Getting specific category posts with appserviceprovider in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get my category latest posts in `main page` in Laravel 5.5 and I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is the code that I have:

```
View::composer('frontend.index', function ($view) {
$categoryone = Cateory::with('products')->where('category_id', $category)
  ->offset(1)
  ->limit(9)
  ->get();
$view->with('categoryone', $categoryone);
});
```

This is the error i get:

```
Class 'App\Providers\Cateory' not found
```

This is my `AppServiceProvider` head:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Category;
use DB;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
....
```

> PS: except my question above, I need to know is there anyway that I
>   can select my categories in admin panel and posts of that be shown in
>   `homepage` instead of I statically load each category from
>   `AppServiceProvider` or no?

#### Explanation

If you worked with WP themes/plugins you can choose what category posts to be shown in front page from some sort of dropdown boxes.

Example:

[image: sample image]

Comment: `Cateory !== Category` as @haidang pointed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you has a error typing

Use `Category` instead of `Cateory`

Comment: i get that bro thanks, but how to get specific category posts?